# How to re-use a method in C#

Tags: c#

So, in the code below, In the last method, I want to re use the second one  `public static Valute GetValuteByDate(DateTime date, string valuteCharCode)`, but I really don't understand what parameters to give.  As you can see, I successfully re-used first method in the second method. Any idea what I can do to re-use the second method in the third one? Or maybe you have some useful information?

```
public static class Api
{
    public static ValCurs GetValCursByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://bnm.md"); //request

        var request = new RestRequest("ro/official_exchange_rates/get_xml=1&date="+date.ToString(), Method.GET); //request

        var response = client.Execute<ValCurs>(request);//deserialization

        if (response.ErrorException != null) { return null; } //throw exception

        return response.Data;
    }

    public static Valute GetValuteByDate(DateTime date, string valuteCharCode)
    {
        var curs = GetValCursByDate(date);

        Valute valuteByDate = curs.FirstOrDefault(valute => valute.CharCode.Equals(valuteCharCode));

        return valuteByDate;
    }

    public static Valute GetMaxValuteByPeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string charCode)
    {
        var maxVal = GetValuteByDate(**?**);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to use the 3rd in the second by passing the same date for start and end.

Comment: I understand, but my task is to use the second in third

Comment: You can not do that.  You cannot force a date range down to an exact date match.  In fact you'd need an endpoint you can call that can handle a date range in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class Api
{
public static ValCurs GetValCursByDate(DateTime date)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://bnm.md"); //request

    var request = new RestRequest("ro/official_exchange_rates/get_xml=1&date="+date.ToString(), Method.GET); //request

    var response = client.Execute<ValCurs>(request);//deserialization

    if (response.ErrorException != null) { return null; } //throw exception

    return response.Data;
}

public static Valute GetValuteByDate(DateTime date, string valuteCharCode)
{
    var curs = GetValCursByDate(date);

    Valute valuteByDate = curs.FirstOrDefault(valute => valute.CharCode.Equals(valuteCharCode));

    return valuteByDate;
}

public static Valute GetMaxValuteByPeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string charCode)
{
    var totalDays = (endDate-startDate).TotalDays;
    List<Valute> result = new List<Valute>(totalDays);
    for(int i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
    {
         result.Add(GetValuteByDate(startDate.AddDays(i), charCode);
    }
    var maxVal = result.Max(p => p.<put here property>);

    return maxVal;
}
}
```

Comment: This answer fits your requirements but the idea to call external api in the loop is not the best. Maybe you don't need all days or something?  In addition take care about returned null value, I think you don't want to put it to result list :)

Comment: I have a xml like this, the value of EUR changes every day, How can I find the max Value of the EUR for example for a specific period, for ex. I will have an object with the following("10.07.2017""10.08.2017","EUR"). and from this period  how can I find the max value ? I tried with Linq but no success...

Comment: <CurrencyDate="10.08.2017" name="Bank">

Comment: <Valute ID="47">

Comment: <NumCode>978</NumCode>

Comment: <CharCode>EUR</CharCode>

Comment: <Nominal>1</Nominal>

Comment: <Name>Euro</Name>

Comment: <Value>21.0384</Value>

Comment: </Valute>
        </CurrencyDate>

Comment: Ok, so you have to iterate

Answer (score 1):

The third one seems to be using a range, so you'd need to call the second one for each day in the range.

```
  for(var day = startDate; date<= endDate; day = day.AddDays(1))
    {
        Valute value = GetValuteByDate(date, valuteCharCode);
        //compare value to the max value and set if higher
    }
```

Note: I didn't test this code so you might have to fiddle with it

Comment: This assumes that the date doesn't take the time into account.  Not to mention how inefficient it's going to be making multiple web service calls like that.

Comment: OP seems to be stern about using the second function inside the third. I think this is the best way to do that.

Comment: yes, I have startDate and Enddate and I have a charcode, I need to find the max value of this charcode in the given period

Comment: juharr: true but he might not have an api call that can return more than 1 day's worth of information.